# Condición dentro de un modal

Tags: php, javascript, html, modal

Necesito hacer un IF dentro de un modal desde una variable id que he pasado en javascript, es decir, tengo un modal al que le paso una serie de variables de un registro desde un click en php. Una de las variables es el tipo de examen del alumno ... SAT, TOEFL, ... etc... lo que quiero conseguir es que según el tipo de examen me muestre unos campos a modificar u otros mediante ifs. Actualmente tengo los ifs en codigo php pero evidentemente no funciona:

El click donde paso todas las variables del registro al modal:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $id;?>" data-id2="<?php echo $type;?>" data-id3="<?php echo $row['exam_status'] ?>"  data-id4="<?php echo $date; ?>"  data-id5="<?php echo $row['cr']; ?>"  data-id6="<?php echo $row['mt']; ?>" data-id7="<?php echo $row['wr']; ?>" data-id8="<?php echo $row['toefl']; ?>" data-id9="<?php echo $row['ielts']; ?>" data-id10="<?php echo $row['clep']; ?>" data-id11="<?php echo $row['gmat']; ?>" data-id12="<?php echo $row['gre']; ?>" data-id13="<?php echo $row['sb1']; ?>" data-id14="<?php echo $row['sb2']; ?>" data-id15="<?php echo $row['sb3']; ?>" data-id16="<?php echo $row['rw']; ?>" data-id17="<?php echo $row['m']; ?>" data-id18="<?php echo $row['er']; ?>" data-id19="<?php echo $row['ea']; ?>" data-id20="<?php echo $row['ew']; ?>" data-id21="<?php echo $row['act']; ?>" title="Add this item" <span style="color:#5bc0de; vertical-align:central" class="open-AddBookDialog glyphicon glyphicon-pencil orange" href="#addBookDialog"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#<?php echo $id; ?>" class="trash" onclick="JSalert(<?php echo $id; ?>);return false;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash red"></span></a>
```

El Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addBookDialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
         <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#333">
                    <form name="form2" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 id="myModalLabel">Edit exam data</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" style="background-color:#111">
                    <div class="control-group">
                    <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" name="exam_id" class="form-control" id="examId" value=""/>
                            <label>Exam type</label>
                                <select name="examtype" id="examId2" class="form-control" style="background: #444; color: #FFF;">
                                    <option id="examId2"></option>
                                    <option>SAT</option>
                                    <option>SAT Subjects</option>
                                    <option>TOEFL</option>
                                    <option>IELTS</option>
                                    <option>ACT</option>
                                    <option>CLEP</option>
                                    <option>GMAT</option>
                                    <option>GRE</option>
                                    <option>OLD SAT</option>                                        
                                </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Status</label>
                            <select name="status" id="examId3" class="form-control" style="background: #444; color: #FFF;">
                                <option id="examId3"></option>
                                <option>Expected</option>
                                <option>Registered</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Date:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId4" name="date" type="date" placeholder = "">
                        </div>       
                        <?php
                        if ($type == "OLD SAT") {?>
                        <div class="form-group">            
                            <label>Critical reading:</label>
                            <input class="form-control"  id="examId5" name="cr1" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">            
                            <label>Maths:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId6" name="mt1" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">            
                            <label>Writing:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId7" name="wr1" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>
                        <?php   
                        } elseif ($type == "TOEFL") {?>
                        <div class="form-group">            
                            <label>TOEFL Score:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId8" name="tf1" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>
                        <?php   
                        } elseif ($type == "IELTS") {?>
                        <div class="form-group">            
                            <label>IELTS Score:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId9" name="ie1" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        } elseif ($type == "CLEP") {?>
                        <div class="form-group">    
                            <label>CLEP Score:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId10" name="cl1" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        } elseif ($type == "GMAT") {?>    
                        <div class="form-group">           
                            <label>GMAT Score:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId11" name="gmat" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div> 
                        <?php
                        } elseif ($type == "GRE") {?>    
                        <div class="form-group">             
                            <label>GRE Score:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId12" name="gre" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>
                        <?php
                        } elseif ($type == "SAT Subjects") {?>
                        <div class="form-group">            
                            <label>Subject 1:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId13" name="sb11" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">            
                            <label>Subject 2:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId14" name="sb21" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">             
                            <label>Subject 3:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId15" name="sb31" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>  
                        <?php
                        } elseif ($type == "SAT") {?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Reading & Writing:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId16" name="rw" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Maths:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId17" name="m" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>E. Reading:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId18" name="er" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>E. Analysis:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId19" name="ea" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>  
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>E. Writing:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId20" name="ew" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>        
                        <?php
                        } elseif ($type == "ACT") {?>    
                        <div class="form-group">    
                            <label>ACT Score:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="examId21" name="ac1" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color:#111">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Aqui es donde paso las variables al modal:

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
     var myexamId = $(this).data('id');
     var myexamId2 = $(this).data('id2');
     var myexamId3 = $(this).data('id3');
     var myexamId4 = $(this).data('id4');
     var myexamId5 = $(this).data('id5');
     var myexamId6 = $(this).data('id6');
     var myexamId7 = $(this).data('id7');
     var myexamId8 = $(this).data('id8');
     var myexamId9 = $(this).data('id9');
     var myexamId10 = $(this).data('id10');
     var myexamId11 = $(this).data('id11');
     var myexamId12 = $(this).data('id12');
     var myexamId13 = $(this).data('id13');
     var myexamId14 = $(this).data('id14');
     var myexamId15 = $(this).data('id15');
     var myexamId16 = $(this).data('id16');
     var myexamId17 = $(this).data('id17');
     var myexamId18 = $(this).data('id18');
     var myexamId19 = $(this).data('id19');
     var myexamId20 = $(this).data('id20');
     var myexamId21 = $(this).data('id21');
     $(".modal-body #examId").val( myexamId );
     $(".modal-body #examId2").val( myexamId2);
     $(".modal-body #examId3").val( myexamId3);
     $(".modal-body #examId4").val( myexamId4);
     $(".modal-body #examId5").val( myexamId5);
     $(".modal-body #examId6").val( myexamId6);
     $(".modal-body #examId7").val( myexamId7);
     $(".modal-body #examId8").val( myexamId8);
     $(".modal-body #examId9").val( myexamId9);
     $(".modal-body #examId10").val( myexamId10);
     $(".modal-body #examId11").val( myexamId11);
     $(".modal-body #examId12").val( myexamId12);
     $(".modal-body #examId13").val( myexamId13);
     $(".modal-body #examId14").val( myexamId14);
     $(".modal-body #examId15").val( myexamId15);
     $(".modal-body #examId16").val( myexamId16);
     $(".modal-body #examId17").val( myexamId17);
     $(".modal-body #examId18").val( myexamId18);
     $(".modal-body #examId19").val( myexamId19);
     $(".modal-body #examId20").val( myexamId20);
     $(".modal-body #examId21").val( myexamId21);
     $('#addBookDialog').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Quieres que el usuario al seleccionar una opción de examen se actualice el formulario?

Comment: Exacto, yo directamente cuando le hago click al botón le paso la variable examId2 donde tiene almacenado el tipo de examen. He añadido el script en mi código.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias utilizar jquery para poder mostrar los campos dependiendo de la opción en el select.

Digamos que estos son los elementos que mostraras si el usuario escoge en el select "SAT"

```
                   <div class="form-group">            
                        <label>Critical reading:</label>
                        <input class="form-control opcion-SAT"  id="examId5" name="cr1" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">            
                        <label>Maths:</label>
                        <input class="form-control opcion-SAT" id="examId6" name="mt1" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">            
                        <label>Writing:</label>
                        <input class="form-control opcion-SAT" id="examId7" name="wr1" id="focusedInput" type="float">
                    </div>
```

Observa que a cada elemento agregue una clase en comun, esta nos servira para mostrar los elementos.

Para obtener el valor de select:

```
$('select#examId').on('change',function(){
var select = $(this).val();
switch(select){
      case "SAT":
      $('.opcion-SAT').show();
      break;

      case "se agregan las otras opciones":
      break;
}
})
```

Cuando se carga el modal todos los input deben de estar ocultos y cada que vez que cambie el select se deberan ocultar para que no se muestren todos.
Espero sea de tu ayuda!

Comment: Hola Cristian. Por lo visto algo estoy haciendo mal porque me siguen apareciendo todos los exámenes. El tipo de examen lo paso con el id examId2

Comment: He añadido el script donde le paso las variables al modal

Answer (score 0):

Lo tengo solucionado, simplemente en el Script le he puesto condiciones tales como:

```
if (myexamId2 == 'TOEFL') {
        $('label[for="SAT_label"]').hide();
        $('label[for="SATS_label"]').hide();
        $('label[for="OSAT_label"]').hide();
        $('label[for="GMAT_label"]').hide();
        $('label[for="IELTS_label"]').hide();
        $('label[for="ACT_label"]').hide();
        $('label[for="CLEP_label"]').hide();
        $('label[for="GRE_label"]').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId5').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId6').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId7').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId8').show();
        $('.modal-body #examId9').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId10').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId11').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId12').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId13').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId14').hide(); 
        $('.modal-body #examId15').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId16').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId17').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId18').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId19').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId20').hide();
        $('.modal-body #examId21').hide();

}
```

Un saludo!